# Stacked area graph in ggplot2 is empty

Tags: ggplot2

I am trying to make a stacked area graph in ggplot2:

```
Zooplankton<-read.table("clipboard".header=TRUE)

TransZoop   Zoop    DensZoop
0   Copepoda    0.066
0   Nauplii 0.425
0   Cladocera   0.199
0   Rotifera    0.269
0   others  0.041
217 Copepoda    0.045
217 Nauplii 0.567
217 Cladocera   0.110
217 Rotifera    0.267
217 others  0.011
462 Copepoda    0.046
462 Nauplii 0.325
462 Cladocera   0.522
462 Rotifera    0.090
462 others  0.017
848 Copepoda    0.043
848 Nauplii 0.020
848 Cladocera   0.928
848 Rotifera    0.009
848 others  0.000
1248    Copepoda    0.019
1248    Nauplii 0.013
1248    Cladocera   0.964
1248    Rotifera    0.003
1248    others  0.000
1765    Copepoda    0.017
1765    Nauplii 0.003
1765    Cladocera   0.980
1765    Rotifera    0.000
1765    others  0.000
3216    Copepoda    0.030
3216    Nauplii 0.003
3216    Cladocera   0.962
3216    Rotifera    0.004
3216    others  0.000
```

When I use the command:

```
Z<-ggplot(Zooplankton,aes(x=TransZoop,y=DensZoop,group=Zoop,fill=Zoop))+geom_area(position="fill")+scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")
```

It turns out like this:
[image]

But when I try to change some graphical parameters, the plot disappears:

```
Z<-ggplot(Zooplankton,aes(x=TransZoop,y=DensZoop,group=Zoop,fill=Zoop))+geom_area(position="fill")+scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + labs(list(x="Distance from margin (m)",y="Zooplankton"))+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=30),axis.text.y=element_text(size=30),axis.title.x=element_text(size=30),axis.title.y=element_text(size=30,angle=90),legend.text=element_text(size=30),legend.title=element_blank(),legend.key.size=unit(2,"cm"),legend.key=element_rect(colour="black",linetype="solid",size=1.5),panel.border=element_rect(colour="black"))
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange, user130200 !. Unfortunately your question seems a bit off-topic, since the GIS component in your question is only `Distance from margin (m)` and it is rather weak.  For your convenience I posted an answer, but voted to close at the same time... It can be asked in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is `panel.border=element_rect(colour="black")`. Add `fill=NA` to prevent it from hiding your plot.

```
ggplot(Zooplankton,aes(x=TransZoop,y=DensZoop,group=Zoop,fill=Zoop))+
  geom_area(position="fill")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + 
  labs(x="Distance from margin (m)",y="Zooplankton")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=30),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=30),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=30),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=30,angle=90),
        legend.text=element_text(size=30),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.key.size=unit(2,"cm"),
        legend.key=element_rect(colour="black",linetype="solid",size=1.5),
        panel.border=element_rect(colour="black", fill= NA)                 ### fill= NA ### 
        )
```

[image]